# TASM 8086 (16-bit): How get sizeof array?

Tags: arrays, size, x86-16, tasm

I tried using the SIZE operator in TASM in order to get the size of an array. But there's a small problem here...

If I use EQU directive to set the data of the array,

```
ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA

ARRAY EQU 10H,20H,30H,40H

CODE SEGMENT
;[...Initialize data segment...]
MOV AX,SIZE ARR
;[...Rest of the code(if any)...]
CODE ENDS

DATA SEGMENT
ARR DB ARRAY
DATA ENDS
END
```

It yields the size as 1.

The most probable for this happening is the way TASM is calculating the size

```
SYMBOL_NAME DB(=1) (*) ARRAY[1+NUMBER OF COMMAS]
```

Is there any way to overcome it..Maybe by using some other directive or by conditionally expanding the macros before assembling..

Output after using the mentioned solution. (DOSBox 0.74)

```
Turbo Assembler  Version 3.0  Copyright (c) 1988, 1991 Borland International

Assembling file:   exp14b.ASM
ADD DI,$-ARR
**Error** exp14b.ASM(12) Can't subtract dissimilar relative quantities
Error messages:    1
Warning messages:  None
Passes:            1
Remaining memory:  476k
```

Comment: You can put 0 at end and count the element till the element at index is 0.

Comment: I'm looking for some assemble time method...What if one of the existing values turn out to be 0?

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion:

```
...
MOV AX,ARR_SIZE
...
ARR DB ARRAY
ARR_SIZE EQU $-ARR
ARR_LENGTH EQU (ARR_SIZE / TYPE ARR)    ; not necessary but useful
...
```

Comment: So TASM doesn't have the MASM operators `lengthof ARRAY` or `sizeof ARRAY`, and you have to calculate it yourself like in NASM?

Comment: @PeterCordes: TASM has `LENGTH` and `SIZE`, but - I've tested it - both fail in the constellation of the OP.

Comment: @PeterCordes : No it didn't and very early versions of MASM didn't either. LENGTHOF and SIZEOF were eventually added to MASM. In TASM the concept of an array has a limited meaning for the purposes of the SIZE operator. The only way to declare an array and have SIZE return a proper size in bytes is if you use DUP. So  if you declare  it as `ARR DW 5 DUP(0)` SIZE will return 10. As well everything after the first comma is ignored when it comes to SIZE. `ARR DW 5 DUP(0), 4 DUP(0)` would still return 10 as would `ARR DW 5 DUP(0), 10h, 11h, 12h`

Comment: What RKHB proposes it the more universal solution if you are looking to assemble with MASM and TASM.

Comment: In the OP's case `ARR DB ARRAY` SIZE is simply returning the size of the first element (1). Everything after the first comma isn't applied to the array. Had it been `ARR DW ARRAY` SIZE would have returned 2 etc.

Comment: My TASM doesn't seem to recognize $-ARR...it's treating it as dollar - arr

Comment: LENGTH operator worked before this..I am not sure why it isn't working now..or did I mix up by sequence of thoughts...Either ways is there any other way out?

Comment: There's a chance that I'm not using the solution in the right way, so I have appended the output with /z option, so that things get easier.

Comment: SIZE returns the size of first element and length always return one ... Just as you'll mentioned.

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow: This is the very first time in 30 years that I've heard TASM decline dollars :-)

Comment: @rkhb he made an edit to the question, he's using your idea the wrong way.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I don't believe it. I think I'm getting trolled.

Comment: @MichaelPetch It doesn't work in my TASM 2.0, could you send me your 16-bit version of TASM?